# Singular or plural? How much

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which sentence is correct:

> - How much **is** the banana and the orange?

or

> - How much **are** the banana and the orange?

Comment: How much are ...

Answer (score 1):

You will hear both.

The form with "is" literally implies a single answer, namely the sum of the prices of one banana and one orange.

The form with "are" technically implies a double answer, namely the price of one banana and the price of of one orange respectively.

Sadly, even native speakers may not express themselves correctly because they forget the flexibility inherent in English. Thus, in practice, ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native speaker but from personal experience the singular is more often used simply for it's flowability and contractiobility.

Technically this can be confusing:

- How much is the orange and the banana?

This sentence when spoken can either be asking for the sum of the two or the price of each fruit, in which case there will be a slight pause before "*and*" and the switch of focus (pointed finger) from the orange to the banana.

Also "**How much is**" is often contacted to "**How much's**".

Notice that in speech the pointing of the finger can play a major role:

- How much are these? (pointing the finger at the orange and the banana).

This way the seller will most probably tell you the price of each fruit.

Notice that there is also a circular movement of the finger when you try to encircle the products you wish to buy, in which case it's better to use "**is**" since you wish to know the total price:

- How much is this? (encircling three bananas and two oranges that lie on the give-out plate)